# How do I transfer a file from to another computer using WinPE command line?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, imaging

I want to develop a custom image for Windows 7 and I am following this [guide](http://benosullivan.co.uk/windows/how-to-image-and-deploy-windows-7-a-complete-guide/comment-page-17/#comments)

I am **having a problem with the [last step](http://benosullivan.co.uk/windows/how-to-image-and-deploy-windows-7-a-complete-guide/comment-page-17/#5)**.

After I create the "install.wim" image at the root of my hard disk I need to transfer it to another computer while in the WinPE command line.

- I have tried to start the computer normally but it gives me an error and gets stuck as "Setup is starting services"
- I cannot detach the hard drive from the computer and install it in another because I am using a VMWare environment.
- xcopy or robocopy give me a permission denied error.
- I have been told to try clonezilla but I'm not comfortable with that.

How can I copy this file to another computer?

Comment: are you saying the entire windows install (and the WInPe environment) is running in a virtual machine?

Comment: Can you attach the virtual hard disk as a secondary disk to another working virtual machine and access it that way?

Comment: uSlackr, I am sure that would work but I am unfamiliar with how to manipulate the virtual machine settings that way.  I will have to do more research on it.

Horatio, The entire Windows install and WinPE is in a virtual machine.

Comment: Note that if the prototype computer is damaged (isn't booting successfully) it is likely that the image of the prototype computer is also damaged.

Comment: If you have a Windows file server available on the network (or can set one up) you can connect to it from Windows PE by using the "net use" command.  Alternatively, depending on which version of VMWare you are running you might be able to redirect a USB disk through to the virtual machine.